# Will Selenium work on Ubuntu with no GUI

Tags: ubuntu, selenium, codeception

I'm using Codeception on various cloud platforms like Amazon AWS and Cloud 9. Neither of which has a GUI by default. My question is, can you run Selenium on this type of system? Or do I need to somehow get a GUI?

Comment: You can use something like phantomjs to do headless testing.

Comment: An example article: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs--net-30545

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Selenium is only a library, and as such it does not particularly care if you are running it on a system that is equipped with a GUI. What you are probably asking is: If I use Selenium to open a browser, is that browser going to work on a system with no GUI. The answer to this is: it depends!

There are headless browsers: browsers that also do not have a GUI component. [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is packaged with Selenium. Another popular browser is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which has third-party Selenium bindings library called [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver). Personally I would **avoid both of these**! HtmlUnit uses a JavaScript engine that none of the current desktop browsers support, and as such the tests are not very reliable. GhostDriver has [not been maintained for 2 years](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver#help-needed), and as such also makes for unreliable results. PahntomJS is definitely an option, as it uses WebKit - the engine that is in Safari and Chrome browsers, but you would have to write your own [API](http://phantomjs.org/api/).

Most systems will allow you to have a virtual GUI. You mentioned Ubuntu, which is a Debian derivative. There are several tutorials on the Net that tell you how to install Xvfb, most of which are incomplete or wrong. On a Debian you install a headless browser like this:

1. Install Xvfb: `apt-get install xvfb`
2. Install a browser. Assuming you are using a Debian server, you will not be able to install something like Firefox with apt-get, because the repositories are not present. Instead Google something like "Firefox off-line install", or whatever browser you want to use, and then use `wget` on your server to grab the package.
3. Unpack the package somewhere like `/usr/local/lib`, and then create a soft link from `/usr/local/bin` to the binary that launches the browser.
4. Now try launching your browser headless. For example, for Firefox you would try: `xvfb-run firefox`. This may produce some errors, which you have to fix. In my case, I was missing the library `libdbus-glib-1-2` which I could install just using apt-get.
5. At this point you will need to launch Xvfb before running your Selenium tests. Most CI servers have a plugin for Xvfb, or you can do it from the command line: `Xvfb :99 &`. See the [docs](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) for additional information.

Comment: This answer is getting upvoted, so I thought I should add: Chrome and Firefox now support headless mode out-of-the-box, without the need for Xvfb. As of Selenium 3.6.0, this is supported from Selenium without anything special.

Comment: One question: If we are using headless browsers like PhantomJS, GhostDriver, HTMLUnit. Do we still need Xvfb ?

Comment: @Darshan Of course: no.