# webgl xvfb google chrome support

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, webgl

how can i get webgl support. here's my setup?

linux (centos OS)
google chrome
xvfb to get google chrome running
chrome driver that selenium uses to run the tests

I need google chrome to have webgl support. how do I get that done?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343755/3124333 It's Firefox-specific, but using a similar procedure might help you?