# Skipped all tests on phpunit with chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, laravel-5, phpunit, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed selenium 3.01, chromedriver 2.27 and chrome 59 on an Ubuntu 16.04.

Everything works on my local machine (running gnome desktop) but not on a test machine (without any GUI).

I started the Selenium with the next command (I don't have a GUI on this machine):

```
xvfb-run java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -jar /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -debug
```

I checked with telnet that it starts on port 4444:

```
root@xxx:~# telnet localhost 4444
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

f
HTTP/1.1 400 No URI
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Server: Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210)

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But when running the tests with phpunit they fail:

```
root@xxx:/var/www/dev.xxx.tt-laravel/site# "vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit" tests/General/NotAuth.php --verbose
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Configuration: /var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/phpunit.xml

SS                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 2 minutes, Memory: 12.00MB

There were 2 skipped tests:

1) NotAuth::test_shops_index_load
The Selenium Server is not active on host localhost at port 4444.

/var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:299
/var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:337
/var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:314

2) NotAuth::test_shops_categories_load
The Selenium Server is not active on host localhost at port 4444.

/var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:299
/var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:337
/var/www/dev.domain-laravel/site/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:314

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 2.
```

and the output from the selenium tab:

```
2017-07-02 17:18:00.738:INFO::main: Logging initialized @497ms
2017-07-02 17:18:00.870:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2017-07-02 17:18:00.917:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5158b42f{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-07-02 17:18:00.938:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6771beb3{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-07-02 17:18:00.939:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @698ms
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 6589
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440175 (9bc1d90b8bfa4dd181fbbf769a5eb5e575574320) on port 16531
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

PS : This is one of the tests:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Modelizer\Selenium\SeleniumTestCase;

// https://github.com/Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium
// https://github.com/Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium/wiki/APIs

require_once(__DIR__.'/../../vendor/hacks/load_env.php');

class NotAuth extends SeleniumTestCase
{

    /**
     * SHOPS MODULES START
     */

    public function test_shops_index_load()
    {
        $url = trim(route('shops_index', [], FALSE));
        $this->visit($url)
            ->see('Top Shops')
            ->see('Help Center3')
            ->seePageIs($url)
        ;
    }

    public function test_shops_categories_load()
    {
        $url = trim(route('shops_categories', [], FALSE));
        $this->visit($url)
            ->see('Automotive')
            ->see('Baby')
            ->seePageIs($url)
        ;
    }

    /**
     * SHOPS MODULES END
     */
}
```

Comment: can you show me your connection code, are you sure that it will work without GUI? how selenium will open the browser?

Comment: @Dennis I'm using https://github.com/Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium, I'll edit my question and put one of the 2 tests I wrote

Comment: try to add $this->setPort(4444); to force port 4444 inside SeleniumTestCase.php 'setUp' method.

Comment: I forgot to mention that everything works on my computer (with gnome).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342632/will-selenium-work-on-ubuntu-with-no-gui
maybe it will help you.
are you tried setPort(4444) ?

Comment: Yes, same thing with setting it to 4444. It takes around 1 minute (probably timeout) per test to fail. But if i set it to a non-used port, it fails in under 1 second.

Comment: are you sure that you run selenium under localhost host?
try /usr/local/bin/selenium.....2.41.0.jar -host 127.0.0.1

Comment: Ohh yes, I can connect to it with telnet.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the exact same issue the past two odd months and have been doing a ton of investigation around this.

I noticed on my environment that locally the whole process works but the exact same setup on a build server failed...

I ended up noticing that on local, I was running and installing everything as the vagrant user. On the build server however (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), I did everything as root and adding items manually to the PATH was impossible as the system is maintained by Puppet.

Noticing that, I changed all the required permissions to Jenkins (ci will be running the tests eventually).

I also globally installed phpunit & phpunit-selenium along with specific versions of all the required tools.

- Xvfb
- Google-Chrome - V59.0.3071.115
- FireFox - V54.0
- Chromedriver - V2.30
- GeckoDriver - V0.16.1
- Selenium Standalone Server - V3.4.0
- PHPUnit - V5.7.21
- PHPUit-Selenium - V3.0.3

Installation I followed:
Java:

```
apt-get -qq install default-jre
```

Google-Chrome:

```
apt-get -qq install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_59.0.3071.115-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
apt-get -qq install -f
```

Firefox:

```
apt-get -qq update
apt-get -qq install firefox
```

Xvfb:

```
apt-get -qq install xvfb
```

Google Chrome Driver. (V2.30):

```
cd ~/
mkdir browser-drivers
cd browser-drivers
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.30/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver*.zip
chmod a+x chromedriver
chmod 775 chromedriver
chown jenkins:jenkins chromedriver
```

Firefox Gecko Driver. (V0.16.1):

```
cd ~/browser-drivers
wget -N https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.16.1/geckodriver-v0.16.1-linux64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver*
chmod a+x geckodriver
chmod 775 geckodriver
chown jenkins:jenkins geckodriver
```

Selenium Standalone:

```
cd ~/
mkdir selenium
cd selenium
wget -N http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.4/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
chmod a+x selenium*
chown jenkins:jenkins selenium*
```

PhpUnit (V5.7.21):

```
curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-5.7.21.phar
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /usr/local/bin/phpunit
# Run from "/var/lib/jenkins" as jenkins user
cd /var/lib/jenkins
su jenkins
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit=5.*'
composer global require 'phpunit/phpunit-selenium=3.0.3'
```

I then also created two scripts to start up both xvfb & selenium after each test effort.

seleniumxvfbup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

Xvfb :8 -screen 8 1920x1080x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset > /dev/null 2>&1 &

export DISPLAY=:8.8

java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=browser-drivers/geckodriver -Dchrome.binary=/opt/google/chrome/chrome -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=browser-drivers/chromedriver -jar selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -port 4444 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Starting selenium server in this way allows me to have individual tests on either chrome or firefox without having to stop/start selenium every time.

Killing the services is as simple as

```
pkill -f selenium & pkill -f Xvfb &
```

and finally

```
chmod +x ~/seleniumxvfbup.sh
chown jenkins:jenkins seleniumxvfbup.sh
```

Just make sure that none of the required files reside in the /root/ dir as this was the main issue in the system failing on my side.

Hope this helps you out...